# Segurança MYSQL Android

Tags: android, mysql, segurança

estou fazendo um Sistema de login .
Porém estou com dúvida:

Faço a conexão com o banco de dados através de PHP?Ou seja eu apenas abriria o link e o Servidor executaria o procedimento?

ou faço diretamente do aplicativo através do connector ?
Se eu for fazer pelo aplicativo,o usuário não poderá ver o login,senha do Servidor ?
Obrigado !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

É Extremamente não recomendável a utilização de "conectores" de bancos no android para bancos externos, pois você iria expor os dados do seu servidor no aplicativo android(.apk), podendo ser descompilado e os dados serem acessados.

Recomendo que faça como o @Piovezan comentou, utilize WebServices!

Listarei algumas **vantagens**:

1 - Mais **segurança** e **estabilidade**.(Os dados de segurança do servidor não estarão expostos no código)

2 - Abstração da lógica de segurança do servidor (Você irá fazer uma requisição e o servidor irá tratar).

3 - A Lógica do webservice poderá ser compartilhada com outros serviços que precisam desses dos dados do seu banco(Qualquer aplicação poderá entrar em contato com o serviço e ter acesso aos seus dados)

Alguns tutoriais que podem te ajudar:

http://www.androidhive.info/2014/01/how-to-create-rest-api-for-android-app-using-php-slim-and-mysql-day-12-2/

http://www.androidhive.info/2012/05/how-to-connect-android-with-php-mysql/

http://www.restapitutorial.com/

Boa sorte!

Comment: Obrigado !Vou seguir suas dicas!

Answer (score 1):

O correto é fazer pelo PHP (web service), assim o aplicativo não tem conhecimento das credenciais usadas para acessar o banco, além dessa porção do código ficar isolada no web service. Além disso a conexão com o banco ficará mais estável (conexões de celular tendem a ser menos estáveis).